# I can't get a vanilla Rails + Turbolinks Shopify App working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, turbolinks, shopify-app

I just went through the [Rails & Turbolinks tutorial](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/authenticate-server-side-rendered-embedded-apps-using-rails-and-turbolinks) - because I am creating a Shopify app for the first time. I got to the stage where my app is loading but all I am seeing is the "Loading..." page which is the 'SplashPage#Index' but it isn't redirecting to my 'Home#Index' like I expect.

I am using `Rails 6.0.3.6`, `Ruby 3.0.1` and I am not using React. I want to just use Rails & Turbolinks if possible to build my app, so that's why I chose that tutorial.

This is the server log (note, I blanked out my IP address for privacy purposes).

```
Started GET "/?hmac=5e2e8c366d75e39831b775be635e4118a99c&host=bWFueS1wcmXlzaG9waWZ5LmNvbS9hZG1pbg&locale=en&new_design_language=true&session=7deccadd83c28b82dd4dd2902fff5c76573f365f637c2a&shop=random-shop.myshopify.com&timestamp=1619310003" for 69.160.XXX.XX at 2021-04-24 19:20:04 -0500

┃ Cannot render console from 69.160.XXX.XX! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1

┃ Processing by SplashPageController#index as HTML

┃   Parameters: {"hmac"=>"5e2e8c366d75e39831b775be635e4118a99c", "host"=>"bWFueS1wcmXlzaG9waWZ5LmNvbS9hZG1pbg", "locale"=>"en", "new_design_language"=>"true", "session"=>"7deccadd83c28b82dd4dd2902fff5c76573f365f637c2a", "shop"=>"random-shop.myshopify.com", "timestamp"=>"1619310003"}

┃   Shop Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."shopify_domain" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["shopify_domain", "random-shop.myshopify.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

┃   CACHE Shop Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."shopify_domain" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["shopify_domain", "random-shop.myshopify.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

┃   Rendering splash_page/index.html.erb within layouts/embedded_app

┃   Rendered splash_page/index.html.erb within layouts/embedded_app (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 6)

┃ [Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do

┃   Rendered layouts/_flash_messages.html.erb (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 76)

┃ Completed 200 OK in 38ms (Views: 24.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms | Allocations: 8450)
```

What could be causing this behaviour and how can I fix it?

What other code would you need to see to help me troubleshoot this properly?

**Edit 1**

Not sure if this has any bearing on anything, but from my `rails console`, when I do `ShopifyApp.configuration.api_key`, I get `nil` returned.

**Edit 2**

When I checked my JS console, I see the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@shopify/app-bridge-utils'
```

But in my `app/javascript/packs/application.js` I have included the following:

```
require("shopify_app")
```

**Edit 3**

Here is the full error from the JS Console:

[image: full-error-from-JS-Console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Even though I am not using NPM explicitly, I needed to still include the `@shopify/app-bridge` utilities into my JS package pipeline.

I did this by running the following commands:

```
$ yarn add @shopify/app-bridge
$ yarn add @shopify/app-bridge-utils
```

It worked like a charm, and now everything is good to go.